# replace break element in xml with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i have below XML which i want to convert to HTML using XSLT

```
<richtext >

<par def="2">
    <run>
        <font size="12pt" name="serif" />A<break />B<break /></run>
</par>
```

i want HTML output like below

```
<p> A<br>B<br><p>
```

Comment: Guys while asking question you should show your effort what you did rather than asking for provide ready made answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your input is wrong. it should be with closing element richtext.
Here with the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xhtml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="break">
        <br><xsl:apply-templates/></br>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT IS LIKE:**

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p>A
         <br></br>B
         <br></br>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMD